# With the skull being malleable at birth, does the shape of your skull affect one's susceptibility to head trauma?

Tags: prevention, cause-and-effect, head-trauma, concussion

Some boxers have an "iron chin" and can take punches better than others. When my nephews were born, it was explained that the shape of the skull is not permanent and changes in the early stages of infancy. This got me thinking, can the shape of your skull help reduce your chance of head trauma such as concussions? If so, can a baby's skull be "shaped" to help reduce this risk throughout their life?

Comment: I'm curious what shape you think would offer protection against head injury?

Comment: I don't have an idea of which would be better. I was just curious if there had been any studies or theories out there that had considered shape as a factor and if any shape is better/worse than another. There are so many different "shapes" of skulls and it seems that could be a reason certain people go unconcious easier than others. Head injuries can have many long term effects on people and anything that could potentially reduce the risk of trauma would be good. I hadn't found anything in my internet searches and wondered if anyone here knew anything.

Comment: What has your research revealed so far? We require at least an effort.